# Integrating MarkitUp and MarkdownSharp with asp.net forms website

Tags: asp.net, markitup, markdownsharp

I'm using markdownsharp with my asp.net forms website.

I want to use MarkItUp as my editor and have found a straight forward article on how to integrate with MVC which seems straight forward enough: http://rsolberg.com/2010/09/asp-net-mvc-markitup-rich-text-editor/

However, how do I do this with a forms website?

How do I get the MarkItDown Textarea on a postback and get the preview to work as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the Javascript and CSS file links in the head portion of the page just as you would with MVC. Then in your form, place a TextArea control. Set the rows and columns as needed.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEditor" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="40" Rows="5" Text="" />
```

Then use JQuery to enable to functionality.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('<%=txtEditor.ClientID%>').markItUp(mySettings);    });
```

Then on PostBack the contents of the editor will be available in the Text property of the TextBox control.

```
txtEditor.Text
```

This is not the only way to do this, you could also use a HTML TextArea control with a runat="server" attribute. Use whatever your personal preference is.

Comment: '<%=txtEditor.ClientID%>' should be '#<%=txtEditor.ClientID%>' which works thanks.

Comment: any idea how to get the preview working witht he form? I know you have to edit previewParserPath in the set.js?

Comment: @DaveB I can't get markItUp.text at code behind. any idea? <textarea id="ContentPlaceHolder1_markItUp" class="markItUpEditor" style="width: 690px" cols="20" rows="20" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$markItUp"></textarea>

Comment: @Mert - To access HTML controls from the codebehind, add the runat="server" attribute to the tag.

Comment: @DaveB thanks for your answer. I figure it out I made a irrelevent mistake on codebehind :)